# Is it possible to modify the attribute of a property at runtime?

Tags: c#, attributes

Is it possible to modify the attribute of a property at runtime?

let's say I have some class:

```
public class TheClass
{
    [TheAttribute]
    public int TheProperty { get; set; }
}
```

Is there a way to do this?

```
if (someCondition)
{
    // disable attribute. Is this possible and how can this be done?
}
```

Comment: Why? Perhaps it's better to set a value on that property so that it doesn't do what you want. Or is this for serialisation?

Comment: Right, so what are you trying to do? Stop a given field from being serialised? Or make it serialised on some basis? If it's either of those, you can always have two fields, one with '[NonSerialised]', that doesn't get saved, and when you decide it should, you set the 'other' one. But we'll need a bit more info on your exact reasoning for this.

Comment: ok, the user can check a checkbox if he wants TheProperty to be serialised or not. So, depending on the user's input, the attribute has to change.

Comment: Hmm. Well I'll be interested to see what Marc suggests; in lieu of that, though, how is the serialisation done? Is it custom xml? or are you just relying on the binary serialisation system?

Comment: In that case, I suggest you can just put your own attribute on it, and modify a value (doSerialise=true); I don't know for sure if this is possible, but it almost certainly should be, via reflection. I would be interested to know if Marc Gravell has a better idea though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends; from a reflection perspective: no. You can't. But if you are talking about attributes used by System.ComponentModel in things like data-binding, they you can use `TypeDescriptor.AddAttributes` to append extra attributes. Or other customer models involving custom descriptors. So it depends on the use-case.

---

In the case of xml serialization, it gets more interesting. Firstly, we can use fun object models:

```
using System;
using System.Xml.Serialization;
public class MyData
{
    [XmlAttribute]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [XmlIgnore]
    public bool NameSpecified { get; set; }

    static void Main()
    {
        var ser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(MyData));

        var obj1 = new MyData { Id = 1, Name = "Fred", NameSpecified = true };
        ser.Serialize(Console.Out, obj1);
        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.WriteLine();
        var obj2 = new MyData { Id = 2, Name = "Fred", NameSpecified = false };
        ser.Serialize(Console.Out, obj2);
    }
}
```

The `bool {name}Specified {get;set;}` pattern (along with `bool ShouldSerialize{name}()`) is recognised and used to control which elements to include.

Another alternative is to use the non-default ctor:

```
using System;
using System.Xml.Serialization;
public class MyData
{
    [XmlAttribute]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    static void Main()
    {
        var obj = new MyData { Id = 1, Name = "Fred" };

        XmlAttributeOverrides config1 = new XmlAttributeOverrides();
        config1.Add(typeof(MyData),"Name",
            new XmlAttributes { XmlIgnore = true});
        var ser1 = new XmlSerializer(typeof(MyData),config1); 
        ser1.Serialize(Console.Out, obj);
        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.WriteLine();
        XmlAttributeOverrides config2 = new XmlAttributeOverrides();
        config2.Add(typeof(MyData), "Name",
            new XmlAttributes { XmlIgnore = false });
        var ser2 = new XmlSerializer(typeof(MyData), config2);
        ser2.Serialize(Console.Out, obj);
    }
}
```

Note though that if you use this second approach you need to cache the serializer instance, as it emits an assembly every time you do this. I find the first approach simpler...

Comment: I'm talking about attributes to include/exclude some properties when serializing.

Comment: so, just by addinga property `NameSpecified` the xmlserializer knows whether he needs to serialize Name ? Or am I missing something?

Answer (score 5):

No this is not possible.  You cannot modify attribute values from metadata, or metadata in general, at runtime

Strictly speaking the above is not true.  There are certain APIs which do allow allow for some metadata generation and modification.  But they are very scenario specific, (ENC, profiling, debugging) and should not be used in general purpose programs.

Answer (score 1):

Attributes are baked into code at compilation time.  The only way you can define new attributes at run time is to generate new code at runtime (using Reflection.Emit, for example).  But you cannot change the attributes of existing code.

Answer (score 1):

You can put Boolean variable in the class to disable/enable the property instead of disabling it at run time.

Comment: could you briefly explain/show how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

You might want to look at this http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/csharpgeneral/thread/5b0d356d-d006-43ff-bfcd-aa90dd8de6db

And Dave Morton's explanation on this blog http://blog.codinglight.com/2008/10/changing-attribute-parameters-at.html

Answer (score 0):

You can implement IDataErrorInfo, then check range in Validate method.

```
    public string this[string property] {
        get { return Validate(property); }
    }

    public string Error { get; }

    protected virtual string Validate(string property) {
        var propertyInfo = this.GetType().GetProperty(property);
        var results = new List<ValidationResult>();

        var result = Validator.TryValidateProperty(
                                  propertyInfo.GetValue(this, null),
                                  new ValidationContext(this, null, null) {
                                      MemberName = property
                                  },
                                  results);

        if (!result) {
            var validationResult = results.First();
            return validationResult.ErrorMessage;
        }

        return string.Empty;
    }
```

In sub class

```
protected override string Validate(string property) {
        Debug.WriteLine(property);
        if (property == nameof(YourProperty)) {
            if (_property > 5) {
                return "_property out of range";
            }
        }
        return base.Validate(property);
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

Sounds like you want to consider implementing [IXmlSerializable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.ixmlserializable.aspx)